# Grid View inside Grid view

Tags: asp.net, view, grid

I have a master grid and a child grid which is one of the column of the master Grid and whose data is getting bound to datasource on rowDataBound of master grid view. Now the thing that I want is to get the value of one of the columns of the master grid on the row command of the child grid. Is it possible in any way?

Please suggest

Vikram

Comment: Wouldn't this get a bit...big?

Comment: This link might help you. [Nested Grid View](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3633561/Build-a-Nested-GridView-Control-with-ASPNET.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In the RowDataBound event of the Master Page Grid (you are already using this event), get a reference to a Control (button, link button) in the child grid and set it's CommandName and CommandArgument properties as needed.